# How does the original ionic distribution restore after synaptic transmission

Tags: neurophysiology

During synaptic transmission the calcium ions around the presynaptic membrane diffuse in due to the influx of Na<sup>+</sup> ions and the resulting depolarization. This happens because the calcium channels are voltage regulated ones. At the same time on the other side of the membrane there is efflux of K<sup>+</sup> ions in order to repolarize the membrane. My question is how does the original ionic distribution restore which is more K<sup>+</sup> on the inside and more Ca<sup>2+</sup> on the outside? What kind of pump does this job and what is the exact mechanism? As contrast to the nerve membrane where the Na<sup>+</sup>/K<sup>+</sup> pump does this. I don't find a pump like K<sup>+</sup>/Ca<sup>2+</sup> pump to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the depolarization in the presynaptic terminal is still sodium-based, it's just that there are *also* calcium channels there. Very little calcium actually moves, as these channels are closely coupled to the synaptic release machinery (see for example [Stanley 1993 Single calcium channels and acetylcholine release at a presynaptic nerve terminal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/089662739390214C)).

The calcium concentration gradient has to be established everywhere in cells that have this gradient (all animal cells, as far as I know), not just at a synapse, since [calcium is typically a powerful "second-messenger" signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_in_biology).

The two common mechanisms for transport are by using the gradient of sodium via [calcium antiporters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-calcium_exchanger) (this mechanism: using sodium or proton gradients to move other ions/molecules, is quite ubiquitous in biology), and via a [calcium ATPase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_membrane_Ca2%2B_ATPase). Calcium transport involves both the external space and intracellular calcium stores such as within the [endoplasmic/sarcoplasmic reticulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoplasmic_reticulum).

In the short term, calcium concentrations are also dealt with via chelation by calcium-binding proteins.

Comment: What about K ions . Is their level is maintained by simple diffusion of K ions or some special type of transporters or ATPase come into action. Anyways thanks the links were of great help

Comment: @Ubaid You've already mentioned the Na/K ATPase - that's the primary way that K concentrations are maintained.